# Lowercasing all words except AND

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for the fastest way to lowercase all letters that aren't a part of AND in a phrase. I want to leave `AND` in its original case, whether it was `and` or `AND` should not change.

For example, `barack AND obama` should test equal to `Barack AND Obama` but not `barack and obama`. (notice the case difference in and)

Here is one approach, but I wonder if there is a shorter way or rather a way that avoids iterators:

```
var str = 'Barack AND Obama'; // should be barack AND obama after
str = str.split(/\s+/g).map(function (s) {
    return s.toLowerCase() != 'and' ? s.toLowerCase() : s;
}).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can lowercase every word that's not exactly AND using a negative lookahead:

```
str = str.replace(/\b(?!AND).+?\b/g, function(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Good approach! I'm interested in others too before I choose the best

Comment: I've seen it used to do pseudo look-behinds. This is probably the most elegant approach to my problem.

Comment: @BrianCray you could improve the performance a bit, by making `.+?` a `\w+`. It avoids backtracking and it avoids all the matches of non-word characters (like spaces), which are matched right now, but `toLowerCase` doesn't change them.

Comment: @m.beuttner Interest - How does `.+?` backtrack?

Answer (score 2):

I think pimvdb has the most elegant solution, but just for variety, here is another one.

```
var str = 'Barack AND Obama';
var arr = str.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if (arr[i] != 'AND'){
    arr[i] = arr[i].toLowerCase();
  }
}
var ans = arr.join(" ");
```

It is not as elegant, but I find it slightly more human-readable and easier to modify if needed in the future, ie add to the list of words that should not be lowercased.

Comment: You don't `split` on anything there, and I think you meant to do `split(' ')`?